# iOS SDK - dealloc implementation - Release child views first?

Tags: iphone, ios, dealloc

I am finishing up an iPad application, and for me, that means filling in all of the `dealloc` methods in my classes.

I have many views in my nib and most of them contain subviews (i.e. `UIView`s, `UILabel`s, etc.). Should I release the child views before releasing the parent? If the parent view is released, will its child views be released, as well?

Sample:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [childView release];  // Do I need this if I use the next line?
    [parentView release];  // Will this perform the line above?
}
```

Both `childView` and `parentView` are properties of my view controller. Both have been retained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything that *you* have retained (whether explicitly or through a retained property) needs to be released for the memory management to be balanced.

Also, you should invoke `[super dealloc]` at the end of your `dealloc` implementation, not the beginning (for instance, because you might depend on superclass resources still being available at the time).

Comment: Both `childView` and `parentView` are properties of my class, and both are retained. In this example, should `childView` be released before `parentView` or does it not matter?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski The order in which you release your properties shouldn't matter unless you have custom accessors that do crazy things.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, because the parent view should have a reference to the child view. Therefore the child wont be released until the dealloc for the parent is called and does a final release to the child.

Comment: @Winder Although true, that information is misleading. Order doesn't matter because order doesn't matter, not because one of your properties retains the other.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, saving your dealloc-writing until you're finishing up work on the app is a backwards way to go. I know it seems like house-cleaning work, but the fact is until you're managing memory properly, you're going to have a very skewed view of how your app really performs.

Ideally you should write your dealloc calls as you write your @synthesize statements. In other words, you add a property to your class, you set it up as a retained property, you write its @synthesize and -release code. That way you know your memory management is basically clean (I mean, at the class property level anyway) and you can code with confidence.

Comment: Very true. I usually do this when I am building a helper class and the property count is no more than two or three. When I am constantly changing my user-interface and renaming controls, this can get tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified that you have subviews from a **NIB**, it sounds like you also may need to pay close attention to the `viewDidUnload` method.

Any views which are automatically allocated from the nib you can implicitly release by setting the outlet to nil. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.subviewOutletOne = nil;
    self.subviewOutletTwo = nil;
}
```

Then for any objects which you explicitly retain, you release them in the dealloc method like you are planning to do:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [myDataArray release];
    [coolAnimatedImage release];
    [myCustomSubview release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Also be sure to check out the [LEAKS](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) instrument. This is a random tutorial for using the built in leak analysis tool. There may be others / better ones. It can a pain to get up and running the first time but is completely worth it.

Comment: Retained views (explicit or implicit) need to be released in **both** `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`. The former is not guaranteed to be called before the view controller is released.

Comment: Your saying that when a view is "unfrozen" by the nib I should release it in the `dealloc`? I have never heard of that.

Comment: See the "Special Considerations" section on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW36 and the last couple paragraphs on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW1